# Cloning a Dual Boot Drive with EZ Gig4

Tags: dual-boot, clone

Has anyone had success cloning a dual boot (Windows 7 + 16.04) system to a SSD with [EZ Gig 4](https://www.apricorn.com/upgrades/ezgig)?

This question is raised because normally writing to a SSD is a ~40MB/Sec process, however, the observed speed is 0.8MB/Sec.  In addition, I have not used the cloning tool to clone a dual boot system.

Answer (score 0):

When there are millions of tiny files, effective speed drops dramatically. A real life example would be that like you have to throw a thousand 1gr stone instead of one 1000gr stone. Same amount of material but, takes much more time.

Also be sure that you are not using USB 2.0 interface.

P.S.
Cloning HDD to SDD is not recommended, because of some performance problems. You better backup your data and reinstall your system.